# How can I tell if my processor is being fully utilized on renders?

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine

I'm trying to understand how to check if all cores of my processor are being used to render.

I also will be moving to a computer with 2 processors. Does anyone have any experience utilizing 2 processors to render more efficiently?

Comment: They are. Look into your task manager.

Comment: Another thread mentioned looking into render settings but I guess that's not the case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the render settings under the performance tab there is an option that says threads, with auto-detect all the cores will be used, alternatively you can select the amount of cores if you select Fixed.

To check all of your processor is being used just open task manager (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd>) and you should see 100% cpu usage.

[image]